# Flexslider multi slide functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, sliders

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this:
I am referencing the flexslider plugin which you can view here: http://flex.madebymufffin.com/

3 Flexslider containers -

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $('#primary-slider').flexslider({
         animation: 'slide',
         controlNav: false
     });
     $('#secondary-slider').flexslider({
         animation: 'slide',
         slideDirection: "vertical",
         controlNav: false,
         directionNav: false
    });
    $('#tertiary-slider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: false
    });
});
```

They each contain 3 images, total of 9 different images: [1a.jpg, 1b.jpg, 1c.jpg], [2a.jpg, 2b.jpg, 2c.jpg], [3a.jpg, 3b.jpg, 3c.jpg].

On initialization they are all synced up and it's perfect.

The challenge, which I am hoping someone can figure out, is if you click / swipe next or previous image on any of the containers, the images should move in the same manner on the other 2 containers. So if you are on container 1 and swipe from 1a.jpg to 2a.jpg, in containers 2 and 3 the same should happen...going from 2a.jpg to 2b.jpg, and respectively for the 3rd container. Likewise, going backwards on any of the containers should echo the same effect on the other 2 containers. I think I am overthinking this and someone with a fresh set of eyes will know exactly what to do...

Any help is much appreciated!

Jono

Comment: This sounds like what you're going for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171709/flex-slider-how-to-add-same-controls-for-two-sliders

Answer (score 1):

I think this can now be accomplished with [Flexslider 2](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) using the `sync` property.

```
sync: "",    //{NEW} Selector: Mirror the actions performed on this slider with another slider. Use with care.
```

Comment: That would be very cool man! I will hook it up this weekend. ( :