# Two sliders with same prev/next control pane on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, flexslider

I am trying to build two sliders on the same page, each with its own prev/next control pane.

The tricky part: when a user clicks on any of the controllers, both sliders have to slide in the respective direction.

I have read the FlexSlider's documentation but it I'm not sure whether it's achievable with its properties/API.

Has anyone tried this or know better sliders for this job?

Thanks.

Comment: What code are you using to display / control these sliders?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm thinking you might have to resort to tweaking the plugins code. Basically re-setting the click events to not only fire on the adjacent slider images, but also fire on the nearby slider images as well ( ..or one with specific id..  ). Even if the plugin would have callbacks, you would have to do way too many things to slide a secondary set of slider images ( assuming that it is not a built in feature ).

Comment: @Joonas: I've just found a partial solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171709/flex-slider-how-to-add-same-controls-for-two-sliders
But I'm trying to figure out how to adapt it on my problem..

Comment: Does flexSlider not have a `sync` option for ganging sliders together?

Comment: Hmm, apparently it does. It is still unclear to me how that works but I'll give it a try.

Comment: The API is unclear but I would guess that you give both of your sliders the same class, say `class="mySlider"`, then in the flexSlider options for both sliders, set `sync: '.mySlider'`.

Comment: Here's an example of the sync: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html I'm just not so sure if that will work with 2 regular sliders. If I were you, I would probably try that code from the question you found.

Comment: Yikes, in the example it says "The slider being synced must be initialized first", which makes cross-syncing two sliders a bit tricky. Ignore my earlier suggestion. Try creating a third, hidden, dummy slider; initialize it first, then sync the other two sliders to it.

Comment: are you only wanting manually operated sliders? If so wiring 2 sliders together is fairly easy

Comment: I managed it, wasn't that hard after all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it, wasn't that hard after all.

Basically I used this solution: [Flex Slider - How to add same controls for two sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171709/flex-slider-how-to-add-same-controls-for-two-sliders) but adapted on prev/next buttons only.

```
$('a.nextButton').click(function() {
                            $('.flexslider').show();
                            var totalSlides = slider.count-1;
                            var currSlide = slider.currentSlide;
                            if (currSlide != totalSlides){
                                var next = currSlide+1;
                                slider.flexAnimate(next);
                            }
                            else{
                                next = 0;
                                slider.flexAnimate(0);
                            }
                        });
$("a.prevButton").click(function(){
                            $('.flexslider').show();
                            var currSlide = slider.currentSlide;
                            if (currSlide !== 0){
                                var prev = currSlide-1;
                                slider.flexAnimate(prev);
                            }
                            else{
                                prev = slider.count - 1;
                                slider.flexAnimate(prev);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```