# Flexslider JS - using 'asnavfor' and 'sync' on 3 sliders?

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm trying to achieve a gallery with 3 divs containing sliders (main image, thumbnail carousel and text information) which are synced. Using the 'as navfor' and 'sync' functions I can get all working except when an image thumbnnail is clicked the text info doesn't sync with JS as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        // The slider being synced must be initialized first
        $('#carousel').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: true,
            slideshow: false,
            itemWidth: 233,
            itemMargin: 5,
            asNavFor: '#slider'
        });

        $('#info').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            controlNav: false,
            directionNav: false,
            animationLoop: true,
            slideshow: false,
            sync: "#carousel",
        });

        $('#slider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: true,
            slideshow: false,
            sync: "#info",
        });
    });

</script>
```

So essentially I want to make #carousel 'asNavFor' both #slider and #info. If I add both individually then the the second supersedes the first. Comma seperated didn't work either. Minimal JS knowledge.
Any help much appreciated...

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this and is struggling - in the end I re-wrote the php of the flexslider module I was using and adapted the css to acheive the effect with two sliders - the main slider produces a 75% width image and a 25% text panel that uses the image title and caption. Example here - http://www.justbecausestudio.com/index.php/portfolio/originals

Answer (score 1):

Check the second response to the question linked below. The author claims the code works to sync 2 or more sliders. My first shot at it failed, but I'm still hopeful that it works.

[Flex Slider - How to add same controls for two sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171709/flex-slider-how-to-add-same-controls-for-two-sliders)

I'll re-post his code here:

The HTML:

```
<div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="image4.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="flexslider_children">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><p>Text 1</p></li>
    <li><p>Text 2</p></li>
    <li><p>Text 3</p></li>
    <li><p>Text 4</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="flexslider_children">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><p>Text 1</p></li>
    <li><p>Text 2</p></li>
    <li><p>Text 3</p></li>
    <li><p>Text 4</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
/** 
* Create the children flexsliders. Must be array of jquery objects with the
* flexslider data. Easiest way is to place selector group in a var.
*/
var children_slides = $('.flexslider_children').flexslider({
  'slideshow': false, // Remove the animations
  'controlNav' : false // Remove the controls
}); 

/** 
* Set up the main flexslider
*/
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  'pauseOnHover' : true,
  'animationSpeed': 2000,
  'slideshowSpeed': 5000,
  'initDelay': 3000,
  // Call the update_children_slides which itterates through all children slides 
  'before' : function(slider){ // Hijack the flexslider
    update_children_slides(slider.animatingTo);
  }   
}); 

/** 
* Method that updates children slides
* fortunately, since all the children are not animating,
* they will only update if the main flexslider updates. 
*/
function update_children_slides (slide_number){
  // Iterate through the children slides but not past the max
  for (i=0;i<children_slides.length;i++) {
    // Run the animate method on the child slide
    $(children_slides[i]).data('flexslider').flexAnimate(slide_number);
  }   
}
```