# Sync flex Sliders - flex-direction-nav(Arrows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I was working on the Slider using flex-slider. I got an Idea of syncing two flexsliders into one as we do to Owl-carousel. As the flex caption animates with the image I have to use two flexsliders because I want the flex-caption animation to differ from the image animation. I've got them synced with the help of this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10178582/8040185)
But now I'm stuck at two points:

1) I want the arrows to be synced too. As you can see in my code I have grouped the flex-direction-navs. Now I want to change both the slides on click of a button, but that does not work as it has layering on it.

2) I want the custom targeting button to be active depending on the active slide. for example, I am on the third slide I want the third targeting anchor tag to be active, like a change of color etcetera.

Hope I explained my problem clearly. If you need any further information please comment below.

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/YJXvPo) link. Followed by code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#main-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideToStart: 0,
    start: function(slider) {
      $('a.slide_thumb').click(function() {
        $('.flexslider').show();
        var slideTo = $(this).attr("rel") //Grab rel value from link;
        var slideToInt = parseInt(slideTo) //Make sure that this value is an integer;
        if (slider.currentSlide != slideToInt) {
          slider.flexAnimate(slideToInt) //move the slider to the correct slide (Unless the slider is also already showing the slide we want);
        }
      });
    }

  });

  $('#secondary-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideToStart: 0,
    start: function(slider) {
      $('a.slide_thumb').click(function() {
        $('.flexslider').show();
        var slideTo = $(this).attr("rel") //Grab rel value from link;
        var slideToInt = parseInt(slideTo) //Make sure that this value is an integer;
        if (slider.currentSlide != slideToInt) {
          slider.flexAnimate(slideToInt) //move the slider to the correct slide (Unless the slider is also already showing the slide we want);
        }
      });
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.slider-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

#secondary-slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev,
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev,
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next,
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  top: unset;
  left: unset;
  right: unset;
  bottom: unset;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover,
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#main-slider .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev,
#secondary-slider .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  opacity: 1;
}

#main-slider .flex-direction-nav .flex-next,
#secondary-slider .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px !important;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="secondary-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <p>Text 1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Text 2</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Text 4</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a rel="0" class="slide_thumb" href="#">slide link 1</a>
  <a rel="1" class="slide_thumb" href="#">slide link 2</a>
  <a rel="2" class="slide_thumb" href="#">slide link 3</a>
  <a rel="3" class="slide_thumb" href="#">slide link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the same logic you made for the links by creating your own arrows. You remove the default one then you add your own listener to move the slider.

For the active link simply add more JS to toggle a class.

Here is an example where you can easily use CSS to adjust the position like you want:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#main-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideToStart: 0,
    start: function(slider) {
      $('a.slide_thumb').click(function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.flexslider').show();
        var slideTo = $(this).attr("rel") //Grab rel value from link;
        var slideToInt = parseInt(slideTo) //Make sure that this value is an integer;
        if (slider.currentSlide != slideToInt) {
          slider.flexAnimate(slideToInt) //move the slider to the correct slide (Unless the slider is also already showing the slide we want);
        }
      });
      $('.flex-prev').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.flexslider').show();
        var c = slider.currentSlide;
        if(c!=0) {
          c--;
          slider.flexAnimate(c);
          $('.slide_thumb[rel='+c+']').addClass('active');
        } else {
          slider.flexAnimate(3);
          $('.slide_thumb[rel=3]').addClass('active');
        }
      })
       $('.flex-next').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
       $('.flexslider').show();
        var c = slider.currentSlide;
        if(c!=3) {
          c++;
          slider.flexAnimate(c);
          $('.slide_thumb[rel='+c+']').addClass('active');
        } else {
          slider.flexAnimate(0);
          $('.slide_thumb[rel=0]').addClass('active');
        }
      })
    }

  });

  $('#secondary-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideToStart: 0,
    start: function(slider) {
      $('a.slide_thumb').click(function() {
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.flexslider').show();
        var slideTo = $(this).attr("rel") //Grab rel value from link;
        var slideToInt = parseInt(slideTo) //Make sure that this value is an integer;
        if (slider.currentSlide != slideToInt) {
          slider.flexAnimate(slideToInt) //move the slider to the correct slide (Unless the slider is also already showing the slide we want);
        }
      });
      $('.flex-prev').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.flexslider').show();
        var c = slider.currentSlide;
        if(c!=0) {
          c--;
          slider.flexAnimate(c);
          $('.slide_thumb[rel='+c+']').addClass('active');
        } else {
          slider.flexAnimate(3);
          $('.slide_thumb[rel=3]').addClass('active');
        }
      })
       $('.flex-next').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
       $('.flexslider').show();
        var c = slider.currentSlide;
        if(c!=3) {
          c++;
          slider.flexAnimate(c);
          $('.slide_thumb[rel='+c+']').addClass('active');
        } else {
          slider.flexAnimate(0);
          $('.slide_thumb[rel=0]').addClass('active');
        }
      })
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.slider-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

#secondary-slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
.flexslider .flex-direction-nav {
 display:none;
}

.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="secondary-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <p>Text 1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Text 2</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Text 4</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li class="flex-nav-prev"><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li><li class="flex-nav-next"><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li></ul>
  <a rel="0" class="slide_thumb" href="#">slide link 1</a>
  <a rel="1" class="slide_thumb" href="#">slide link 2</a>
  <a rel="2" class="slide_thumb" href="#">slide link 3</a>
  <a rel="3" class="slide_thumb" href="#">slide link 3</a>
```

Comment: This is working like a charm. As expected. only one more thing is left the custom navigation dots are not getting an active link.

Comment: One last thing is left as i click on arrows the custom navigation is not changing as it should go to next or previous.

Comment: Take your time ill be waiting.

Comment: @MohammedWahedKhan it should be ok now, the arrow are linked with the custom navigation